# Change I make to code behind not updating when I publish my web application

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, iis

I have an ASP.net that I built in VS2010 running in iis7 however when I go back into VS and make updates to the code behind file and re-publish the application still acts as it has before I made the changes.  I have tried deleting and republishing all the files and restarting the app pool but it still doesn't affect how the application behaves.

Comment: What change did you make?  Maybe your changes don't do what you think they do?

Comment: @BioBuckyBall - I just love this site.  Almost every time I post an answer, someone comments an even more likely answer!  :)

Comment: Is your application use dynamic compilation, or do you publish to a DLL in the bin folder?

Comment: dll in the bin folder. @BioBuckyBall, initially I was trying to add dynamic control addtion on a dropdown selection but then I tried much simpler code as to change the text in text box to code I had already written and proven worked.

Comment: Copied and pasted my code into a new application.  Everything works, including my changes and I can make changes and they apper when I publish. *shrugs* Still sort of baffled but happy to be moving on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DO NOT publish your vb and cs file on there server unless you feel like having your source code potentially exposed. There have been multiple vulnerabilities that have allowed code download.

Publish the application to a folder via the visual studio publish  menu.
On the server, go into your temporary aspnet folder for example:
c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files
and find your app and delete it. If you cannot delete the files stop the worker process (w3wp.exe) or restart iis.

Republish and all should be good. If you are in doubt if that version is getting executed then add some logging in the new version or trace information.

Comment: Though I certain this would work. It didn't  and I am dumbfounded.  I redid a simple webapp that dynamically places a control on the page and it worked.  I went back in and changed the code behind and that worked.  So I very confused why this is not working for my original application.  I went into v2.0. (etc) but actually found it under Framework64/v4.0 and restarted iis, deleted the applicatioin, republished and it still is no dice.

Comment: are you absolutely certain the assembly you are deploying has this code in it (ie its the right assembly) and that its not a code error causing your new code to not be hit? have you tried adding logging code at the top of some method? what specifically isnt getting called that you think should? I almost have to think its the technique you are choosing isn't working, as I've never seen this not work as long as your assembly contains the right code. One other option is to get remote debugging setup, then you can check the loaded modules to ensure they are correct. I would reversion libs first.

Comment: To the absolute best of my knowledge. The application works but after reviewing it with my risk manager there are some changes she would like implemented. So I wan't to dynamically add controls based on some selections. So just to test the waters I simply tried to add a control like so (this is not copied from my code) under Page_Load `myForm.Controls.Add(someButton);` and it didn't appear.  So I simply tried to change a text value from a textbox that I had previously changed the value of and it is still displaying the oringial value.

Comment: is it possible the issue lies in web.config?  I am notice with the second test app I made that I have to go back in a delete out about four sections from the section groups to get the page to display or I get a 500.19 error?

Comment: doubtful. Add a new textbox in your aspx. Give it a default value of "hello". in your cs code behind, set its value to "from code behind". If it doesn't show up - then its not getting deployed or your browser is possibly caching the result.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

project-->Property's--> Package / product web--> Items to deploy --> All files in this project folders

now publish your project.
your new files also added in publish folder. . .

Comment: Thank you, for me this solved the problem with some files not being published even though they were changed.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options for publishing an ASP.NET site to a server:

- Copy the .aspx AND aspx.vb (or .aspx.cs) files to the server.  The first user to hit the server causes compilation so it takes a little bit of extra time for them.  Once that's done, subsequent hits should not be impacted.
- Copy just the .aspx files - and a compiled DLL to the server.  The DLL contains the compiled code so it doesn't exist on the webserver.  The first user does not have to wait for compilation and the VB or C# source code is not on the server, potentially accessible to hackers.

It sounds like you've compiled the site to a DLL but that DLL isn't getting published to the server when you re-publish.  Have you recompiled the site before publishing?

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue with WPF single file exe publish.
while debugging from VS my changes were visible.
But when I pasted the exe to deployment folder, the changes weren't there.
I had to change the version number to see my changes when I run the exe from the deployment folder.

I may have to do with how single file exes are handled. The extracted cache may not be getting updated.