# Code Changes in visual studio are not taking place when deployed on IIS

Tags: visual-studio

I have cloned a .net web application to Visual Studio 2017.I have made some changes  to source file in a project and cleaned and built it. my solution file has 52 projects and all the projects will build without any error. Once I deploy it in IIS server and attach the process to visual studio, it hits the breakpoint but runs the old code itself.
Any help will be appreciated as this is delaying the work!!!!

Comment: Are you deploying the correct `.PDB` files?

Comment: Refs or duplicates: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6385537/1531971 https://stackoverflow.com/q/7112091/1531971