# ASP.NET site not updating after changes

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

So, I have a pretty basic ASP.NET site that was built and published via ftp through VS.  Original publication went fine, as did the first few updates. But now I've made page changes (css as well as in the aspx files) and they don't seem to get pushed to the server. I believe that my code behind (C#) files are being updated since there are a few visual elements I call in the code. When I look at the ASPX files, they have old dates and the code is the prior version.  VS says the publishing succeeded, and the host (GoDaddy) says there's no caching or quota issues on their side.  If I upload a new dummy page it goes through... so it looks like updated pages are the issue.

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried updating the files through another ftp client?

Comment: I haven't... it seems odd that the C# code behind is being updated (apparently) while the ASPX portion is not. I'll have to refresh myself on using something other than the VS publishing function :(

Answer (score 0):

If it's styles have you tried doing a hard-refresh on your browser? If everything is saying the files are updated then maybe you have a locally cached version.

Comment: That’s the issue, it doesn’t appear the files are being uploaded in spite of VS saying that it published

Comment: Out of curiosity are you compiling your code before uploading it?

Comment: Well, as I understand it... the codebehind is compiled during publishing, the aspx (which is the problem) is just copied.

Comment: This could be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7112091/change-i-make-to-code-behind-not-updating-when-i-publish-my-web-application

Maybe the DLLs aren't copying or my favorite, the Bin folder isn't being emptied.

Another option just for testing is to go through the Publish settings again:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/quickstart-deploy-to-a-web-site?view=vs-2019

Finally try publishing to a local folder and manually copying:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/quickstart-deploy-to-local-folder?view=vs-2019

Comment: Thanks, yes... I've seen threads discussing that.  Frustrating as hell but that's next up for things I'm going to try.  Manually copying has worked, there's only a few pages and most of the heavy lifting is in the C# which does seem to be getting updated.  Sheesh...